# change secure-file-priv in mysql on osx

Tags: mysql, angularjs, database, macos, csv

I am trying to print my result tables into a csv file or a text file and I use into outfile in mysql but I get this error: 
ERROR 1290 (HY000): The MySQL server is running with the --secure-file-priv option so it cannot execute this statement

I have tried to set this secure-file-priv to "" but i cant really find my.cnf file in my mac. The locate result of my.cnf is like:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.7.16/mysql-test/include/default_my.cnf
/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.7.16/mysql-test/suite/federated/my.cnf
/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.7.16/mysql-test/suite/ndb/my.cnf
/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.7.16/mysql-test/suite/ndb_big/my.cnf
/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.7.16/mysql-test/suite/ndb_binlog/my.cnf
/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.7.16/mysql-test/suite/ndb_ddl/my.cnf
/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.7.16/mysql-test/suite/ndb_memcache/my.cnf
/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.7.16/mysql-test/suite/ndb_rpl/my.cnf
/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.7.16/mysql-test/suite/ndb_team/my.cnf
/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.7.16/mysql-test/suite/ndbcluster/my.cnf
/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.7.16/mysql-test/suite/rpl/extension/bhs/my.cnf
/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.7.16/mysql-test/suite/rpl/my.cnf
/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.7.16/mysql-test/suite/rpl_ndb/my.cnf
```

I dont think any of them is the one that I need to add [mysqld] secure-file-priv="" to. 
Also I tried to set it in mysql but it's read only and I cannot change it. I even tried to to stop and restart my mysql after adding a my.cnf file manually in /etc/ but then I was not able to start the server again and use mysql.

Comment: show us the actual command. You probably just need to designate the output file to another directory.

Comment: The value of my secure-file-priv is now null, so basically i cannot write or read from any directory

Comment: select * from some_table into outfile "somepath/test.csv"

Comment: fire up mysqlworkbench. under Status and System Variables, search for secure_file. See if you can turn the flag off.

Comment: there is no variable called secure-file-priv

Answer (score 5):

I am using mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.20, for osx10.12 (x86_64)
Followed below steps to changes -secure-file-priv

1. Look for "my.cnf" file which is located at /usr/local/etc
2. add secure-file-priv = "" into my.cnf
3. restart mysql using /usr/local/opt/mysql/support-files/mysql.server restart

After restart I am able to use OUTFILE command on mysql.

Answer (score 1):

I reviewed setting on MySQL Workbench.
In "Options Files", it was set to the correct value. But in "Administration - Status and System Variables", it keeped as default value NULL. Although I restarted the server.

After some researches, I found it was cased by the wrong file permission. What I had at the beginning is: 
-rw-------   1 root  wheel             31 Mar 24 13:31 my.cnf

And I use command chmod 0755 changed the permission to:
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel             31 Mar 24 13:31 my.cnf

Then restart the server, I can see both "Options Files" and "Administration - Status and System Variables" have the same value and status.

Comment: If you cannot find my.cnf,try command "/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql -u root --verbose --help | grep my.cnf" to know: order of preference, my.cnf, $MYSQL_TCP_PORT,
/etc/my.cnf /etc/mysql/my.cnf /usr/local/mysql/etc/my.cnf ~/.my.cnf

Comment: Hi rinkchin, welcome to [so]. Please note that [comments are temporary and could be deleted anytime](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). If you have additional information to provide, please update your answer by clicking on the **"[edit]"** link under the post. [See here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19756/204869) for details. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is what it looks like on my server. I can't put a screen shot into the comments.

[image: This is what it looks like on my server;]

Comment: double click in the value column and enter a new value?

Comment: what do you mean, no use? set it to OFF. restart the server.

Comment: I can't change it

Comment: login to the mysql server connection with an admin user.